# After Scaffolding Identity "This localhost page can’t be found" HTTP ERROR 404" error Occurred

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I am using Asp.net 6 with Generic repository pattern. Everything works fine until I scaffolded Identity. After adding identity I am facing "This localhost page can’t be found" HTTP ERROR 404" Error.

Please Helo me to solve this issue. I am added My program.cs and ApplicationDbContext.cs file below.

Program.cs :

```
using CommercialERP.DataAccess.Data;
using CommercialERP.DataAccess.Repository;
using CommercialERP.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();;

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=User}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
namespace CommercialERP.DataAccess.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<BuyerSelectList> Buyer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CnFAgentSelectList> CnFAgent { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding [Area("AreaName")] for all the controllers will resolve this issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0#areas-for-controllers-with-views

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33173211)

Answer (score 0):

Add `builder.Services.AddRazorPages();` and `app.MapRazorPages();` , because Scaffold Identity uses Razor Pages.